# String splitting with Multiple Delimiters not trimming the resultant strings

Tags: regex, string, split

My use case is to split a string on multiple delimiters. Say `, and \n`

I have something like this:

```
String str = "abc
              xyz, jkl"

String[] tokens = str.split(",+|\\n+);
```

My  resultant tokens are like this:

```
abc\n (i.e. abc with a new line) 
xyz and jkl are correctly trimmed.
```

Basically all ',' separated strings were correctly split whereas the '\n' separated string had a '\n' appended to them. I was wondering why the \n appends with them and is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're on windows and there's a carriage return `\r` (which distinct from `\n`) in there too.

Try this:

```
String[] tokens = str.split("[,\\n\\r]+");
```

If tokens are not expected to contain spaces, you can also trim off whitespace from tokens during the split by adding `\s` to the split regex:

```
String[] tokens = str.split("[,\\n\\r\\s]+");
```

Comment: You are correct. I was testing through Windows Browser so maybe it was adding a carriage return.